# can i access sequelize from outside the database provider writing raw query in nestjs using sequelize

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs

```html
export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'Sequelize',
    useFactory: async () => {
      const sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.PG_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT),
        database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
        username: process.env.PG_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
      });
      sequelize.addModels([OrderModule]);
      await sequelize.sync();
      return sequelize;
    },
  },
];
```

Can I access the sequelize outside the file, so that i can use raw queries?
Is there decorator or something which i can use to access the sequelize to write the raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.
We can use the @Inject to access the sequelize from the provider.